# Where are the Visual Studio 2012 SDK Samples?

Tags: visual-studio, sdk, visual-studio-2012

I have just installed Visual Studio 2012 SDK and I cannot find any files.

The installer used more than 100 MBs on disk - but where are the files?

I searched the Start menu and found only links to web. The reference pages says that there are some source code samples, but where are these??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems that there is only [VS 2010 SDK](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Visual-Studio-2010-SDK-ddfe1372).

I found that the solution file is set to version 11.0 (i.e. VS 2012).

Answer (score 1):

Full download here
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/VIsual-Studio-2013-SDK-728822a7

individual links here
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsx/archive/2014/05/30/vs-2013-sdk-samples-released.aspx

Comment: Question (quite old by now) was specific to VS 2012 version. Please consider adding to your (much recent) answer that those are related to VS 2013 instead.